# Nagios to monitor hosts behind a host

Tags: nagios

I have a Nagios setup that is monitoring multiple Windows servers, workstations and Cisco switches on a network.

We are planning to add a second network interface to one of these Windows 2008 servers, and have a small network that is separated from our main LAN. This network will have a switch and a couple of workstations.

Will it be possible for Nagios to monitor this network? I was wondering if there is an agent that I can install on the Windows 2008 server(with two network interfaces) and then route all my checks through it? The Nagios server is located at a remote location so adding an additional network interface to it and plugging it to the separate LAN switch is not an option here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could configure the Windows server as a router between the two lan and insert static routes in Nagios server and other-network's server if they have already a default gateway.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this was the practical solution. I tried to set it up with help from a few online resources including http://www.techrepublic.com/article/managing-routing-and-remote-access-in-windows-server-2003/5089192.

But the problem with the above setup is that it's more like port forwarding. I want to be able to ping the hosts behind the server and also access all ports. Is this possible? Would you have any useful links?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu3xJINBpts You should not use NAT. You shoud use lan routing ( 05:43 of the video )

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows server were running Linux, NRPE would do exactly what you want (there's even a specific use case that talks about this!)

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a direct Windows port of NRPE. I use [NSClient++](http://www.nsclient.org) to monitor my Windows systems - maybe you could create a check command of some sort that checked the devices on the other network.